# As it wishes (or) As per its wish

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Original quote is *"Only dead fish go with the flow"*. I just tried to explain it to my friend and said,

> *"Only dead fish go along with the flow where it goes. Alive fish swim against the flow or to any direction **as it wishes**"*

Is that ***"as it wishes"*** correct? or should that be ***"as per its wish"***? or both are wrong?

Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you're saying **fish swim**, that means you're using the word **fish** in its plural form. To make the rest of the sentence consistent with the things you say at the beginning, you also need a plural pronoun at the end: **or in any direction they want to swim**.

Comment: @Cookie Monster thanks for your clarification. What if that's a singular fish? And also I want to know "as it wishes" & "as per its wish" are correct or not?

Comment: I think, grammatically speaking, they're correct. The question that we should be asking is whether it's idiomatic to say *as it wishes* or *as per its wish*.

Comment: You could simply say: **Fish that are alive go wherever they like.**